# How to use a dynamic property value in a jQuery widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, global-object

I have a javascript that returns a value whenever I choose an option from a dropdown menu.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        function calculateVals() { 
            //dropdown menus      
             var valuestart = $("select[name='timestart']").val();
             var valuestop = $("select[name='timestop']").val();

             //create date format          
             var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestart).getHours();
             var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + valuestop).getHours();

             var hourDiff = timeEnd - timeStart;                         

             return hourDiff;  

        }
        $("select").change(calculateVals);
        calculateVals();
    });
```

The script above returns a number which I need to add to a jquery plugin below. I need to add it to the `max` option but I get the error `calculateVal is not defined`.

```
$(function(){
    $("#slider").slider({
        range: "min",
        value:  8,
        min: 1,
        max: calculateVals(), //my attempt
        step: 1,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#amount").text(ui.value);
        },
         stop: function(event, ui) {
            $("#notifications").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
    $("#notifications").val( $("#slider").slider("value") );
});
```

Comment: @gdoron thanks i dont see it tho haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the function to the global scope:

```
function calculateVals() {       
    //code here...
    return someResult;                                           
}

$(document).ready(function() {
        $("select").change(calculateVals);
    calculateVals();
});
```

And even better, learn what does DOM ready means, as you misuse it.

- You should have only one ready handler.
- Only code relevant to DOM elements should be there.

**Update:**

You can later on change the slider max with:

```
$( "#slider").slider("option", "max", calculateVals());
```

Comment: Thank you! Would some extra code make this dynamic? When i click my dropdown menu and choose an option nothing happens.

Comment: @CyberJunkie. I got the feeling your problem lies here `//code here...` `:)` and anyway I don't know what you call dynamic, nor what exactly is the current problem.

Comment: you are right! I added the missing code to the answer. It calculates an hour difference between 2 times i select from the 2 dropdown menus and returns the result. The result I'm trying to add to the jquery function in `max` option which alters a slider. The function executes only when i load the page

Comment: @CyberJunkie. You can later on change the slider max with `$( "#slider").slider("option", "max", calculateVals());`

Comment: do you mean like this? `$("select").change(function() {   $( "#slider" ).slider("option", "max", calculateTime());  });` I tried with no success..

Comment: @CyberJunkie. For example... I'm going to sleep now, we can continue later... Good luck and good night.

Comment: @CyberJunkie. Did you have doubts about it...? just bragging because it worked. `:)`

Comment: I'm always doubtful in js haha. You've earned bragging privilege

Answer (score 2):

Try defining the `function` out side the ready block:

```
function calculateVals() { 

             //code here...

             return someResult;                                          
}



$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(calculateVals);
    calculateVals();
});
```

Comment: Thanks I tried. I don't get an error but nothing happens when I click the select menu. `someResult` should return a number which should make something happen on change.